# how to read in unknown number of strings using a loop, C++

Tags: c++, string, loops

```
void getFileName(ifstream& inData)
{   

string filename;

cout << "please enter the location of the file you wish to input: " << endl;
getline(cin, filename);

inData.open(filename.c_str());

if (!inData)
{cout << "there was an error with the file you entered" << endl;
exit(0); }
}
```

So I've opened my file but I need it to read in an unknown number of strings.
I need to count these strings in this function then count each character in the next function.  I am used to just doing something like

> inData >> s1 >> s2 >>s3 >> ect.....

this is my first time using unknown amounts of data.  I am not sure if I need to read it in as one big file then go back and count the words and characters or if I need to read it in string by string.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crucial issue here is what you called 'the next function'. Do you need to read all the string and then call the next function once giving it all the strings you've read? Or do you need to call the next function many times, each time calling it with one of the strings you've read?

If it's the former then you need to save all the strings in a vector, if it's the latter then you don't need a vector.

Here's the vector version

```
vector<string> v;
string s;
while (inData >> s)
    v.push_back(s); // save the string in the vector
cout << "the count of strings is " << v.size() << '\n';
the_next_function(v);
```

See how `the_next_function` is called only once. Using a vector will count the strings for you, use the vector `size()` method to get the count of strings.

Here's the non-vector version

```
string s;
while (inData >> s)
{
    the_next_function(s);
}
```

This time `the_next_function` is called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(getline(tmp,inData) != EOF)
    count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that this is homework.

Nevertheless, here is a "nudge": [Reading text files with C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/70805/).

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with one of the [standard algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) functions, namely [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). You can use it with [iterator helpers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) like [`std::istream_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Use the above to put [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) into a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The number of words can be found through the [vector size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).

Comment: Seriously? It's homework 99%. If you want his homework *(only homework has IO, work has parameters)* to clearly spell "cheat", give him an answer this. It's obviously out of his league. :)

Comment: @CodeAngry Good point, removed code and only have the functions/classes needed.